# how to reconnect with server

Tags: qt

I am using QTcpsocket and QtcpServer to implement client server resp. my client program waits till server starts and connect it. I want to reconnect with the server , when server  get down  after connection, but above code gives strange behaviour, it creates a lot of instance of server, and my program got hang.Please give suggestion to fulfil my aim, and please explain what is the problem in following code, it is a slot,in client program, connect with disconnected() signal.

```
 void TcpClient::connectionClosedByServer()
 {
  ui->lStatus->setText(tr("Error: Connection closed by server"));
  closeConnection();
  while(tcpSocket->state()!=QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
  {
     tcpSocket->abort();
     tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost,6015);
     sleep(6);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intead of `sleep(6)` try to use `tcpSocket->waitForConnected(6000)`, otherwise your connection requests will never timeout.